# Emacs on Windows + SSH: subshell spurios characters?

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, ssh

I'm trying to connect via SSH to a remote shell, using Emacs on Windows XP. I'm currently using Putty, but I'd like to switch to Emacs.

I can't find a way which works right. The best I've achieved is running Plink (command line version of Putty) as a subshell, but I'm still getting spurious characters and duplicated prompts like this:

```
Last login: Fri Jun 18 11:09:11 2010 from XXXXX
^]0;root@XXXXX:~^[root@XXXXX ~]# ls
ls
file-1.cfg              file-10.log         file-100.pcap
^]0;root@XXXXX:~^[root@XXXXX ~]# 
^]0;root@XXXXX:~^[root@XXXXX ~]#
```

I guess those sequences with a "^" prefix are escape characters, but I can't find a way to get them translated, or to get rid of them. I've tried this:

```
(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
(let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Programmi/Putty/plink")
      (explicit-plink-args '("root@XXXXX")))
    (shell))
```

Any hint? Have you got a way to run a Secure Shell inside a native Windows version of Emacs?

Software: GNU Emacs 23.1.1, plink.exe version 0.60, Windows XP SP3

Thanks.

Comment: ^[ is ASCII ESC - so yes, the first char looks like an Escape sequence. Could it be setting the colors in your prompt? It's been a while for me, but I think you can set the prompt in your .*shrc conditionally; so if you see a ssh link then maybe don't use that prompt, or use a simpler prompt that doesn't employ escape sequences. This isn't something you'd do in emacs; you'd do it on the remote machine that hosts the shell.  looking at it again, could it be the ansi-color thing that is causing your headache?

Comment: Thanks, Cheeso. Since that is a shared login, I would prefer not to customize it. I hoped there was a way to make Emacs ignore those escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints describes how to use `ansi-term-mode` for ssh connections to remote hosts.

The problematic sequences look (vaguely) like the standard Bash prompt to set the title bar in `xterm` to the current directory etc. You may be able to get a different default prompt by setting the `TERM` environment variable when creating the SSH connection, so that Bash won't think your terminal is an `xterm`. Try with `TERM=emacs` (adapt to the syntax of your shell as necessary).  If you succeed, you might not need `ansi-term-mode` at all, although it could still be useful if you have `ls` directory listing colorization etc.

Comment: I don't use Emacs on Windows anymore (sigh of relief), therefore I can't check out your suggestion.  Thank you anyway.